# Regex that ignores a part of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find html tags in a text, like this:

```
'<span style="background-color: #aaaaaa">'
```

But the color part can change ( like to #bbbbbb )... I think I can use regex for this, right? But I'm not sure how I can just ignore the color part of it...

Can you help me? Is this possible?

Thank you so much ^^

Comment: before rambling down the risky road of regex on HTML - read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5053002) :D

Comment: use a proper HTML parser

Comment: Hmm.. does it matter that I'm the one putting the html tags in the text?

Answer (score 1):

try this 
    `'<span style="background-color: #aaaaaa">'.match(/#[0-9a-fA-F]+/)`

Comment: Don't you think using `match(/#[0-9a-fA-F]+/g)` would be better to capture multiple colour codes thar might be included in the string. Your example will only return the first one. **Example** `'some text #ffff here <span style="background-color: #aaaaaa">more text </span>'.match(/#[0-9a-fA-F]+/g)`

Comment: I will try it with the /g!

Comment: I doubt this can help with the problem or even work at all. To convince me otherwise, please explain how your proposed solution works and how it solves the problem.